# Open Pdf with Specific page without setting acrobat exe file?

Tags: c#, pdf

I know about this

```
Process myProcess = new Process();    
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "acroRd32.exe"; 
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" C:\\example.pdf";
myProcess.Start();
```

but some windows system does not know, where is the acroRd32.exe or Acrobat.exe, I have no access to registry.
Can I open pdf file on specific page without using  **myProcess.StartInfo.FileName** ?